# Block a file with Powershell

Tags: windows, file, powershell, powershell-4.0, alternate-data-stream

I want to block (not unblock) a file with Powershell.  I want to cause Windows to believe that a file on disk was downloaded from the internet, or whatever other scenario exists such that files become blocked.  I need this to test how some software I'm developing behaves in the presence of a blocked file.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're just trying to add the zone identifier you could try something like this:

```bsh
$data = "[ZoneTransfer]
ZoneId=3"

Set-Content example.txt -Stream "Zone.Identifier" -Value $data
```

Comment: I used the following for the newline in $data:   $data = "[ZoneTransfer]`nZoneId=3"

Comment: Applying the comment from @SFun28 to the answer yields the one-liner:
``Set-Content example.txt -Stream "Zone.Identifier" -Value "[ZoneTransfer]`nZoneId=3"``