# How to block an unblocked .net assembly

Tags: c#, .net

I have unblocked some self-made .net libraries and was looking to kind of re-block them. I cant find anything about it there is also just an `unblock-file` command in the microsoft docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/unblock-file. How can i block a file?

**Edit** Work around - works for me: [Block a file with Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49583470/block-a-file-with-powershell)

Comment: http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2011/07/detecting-and-changing-files-internet.html

Comment: great resource, thank you! Make it an answer its exactly what i needed.

Comment: Link-only answers are not allowed here (which is a good thing!), but I'm glad I was able to help!

Comment: I see answers having 100+ upvotes by providing "just" a link.